# DRY conformance for this html code

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, dry

This code uses angularjs ng-table module to display values in a table.

The relevant html code looks like this;

```
<div ng-controller="ViewCtrl" class="container">
    <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>

        <tr>            
            <th>price_alert</th>
            <th>lastPrice</th>
        </tr>

        <thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in $data">
            <td data-title="'price_alert'" ng-class="{ red: item.lastPrice < stk.price_alert }>
                ${{item.price_alert}}
            </td>
            <td data-title="'lastPrice'" ng-class="{ red: item.lastPrice < stk.price_alert }>
                ${{item.lastPrice}}
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The CSS code;

```
.red { color: red; }
```

The controller code;

```
controller('ViewCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'moment', 'ngTableParams',
        function ($scope, $http, $timeout, $window, $configuration, $moment, ngTableParams) {
            var tableData = [];
            //Table configuration
            $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
                page: 1,
                count: 100
            },{
                total:tableData.length,
                //Returns the data for rendering
                getData : function($defer,params){
                    var url = 'http://127.0.0.1/list';
                    $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
                        tableData = response.data;
                        $defer.resolve(tableData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
                        params.total(tableData.length);
                    });
                }
            });
        }])
```

In the html code, there is repetition for this condition to show text color `ng-class="{ red: item.lastPrice < stk.price_alert`. How can the code be modified to keep to DRY (don't repeat yourself) principle, if possible?

Comment: I don't think you can DRY html - it's not a programming langauge

Comment: Thanks. Is it correct to conclude that declarative languages cannot be made to follow DRY?

Comment: I have no idea, as HTML isn't a programming language so any comparison with a programming language is redundant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you only want to eliminate the single extra "red" class declaration.  To do that, put your ng-class in the tr like this:

```
    <tr ng-repeat="item in $data" ng-class="{ red: item.lastPrice < stk.price_alert }">
        <td data-title="'price_alert'">
            ${{item.price_alert}}
        </td>
        <td data-title="'lastPrice'">
            ${{item.lastPrice}}
        </td>
    </tr>
```

And then change your css to this:

```
.red td { color: red; }
```

You can't nest an additional table inside this row with this css, but I'm guessing you don't need to.